# Hybridauth on Codeigniter Could not load the Hybrid_Auth class

Tags: codeigniter, class, github, composer-php, hybridauth

I have installed `hybridauth` via composer and then followed the steps given [here](https://github.com/ApacheEx/CodeIgniter-HybridAuth), but always get the following error:

```
Could not load the Hybrid_Auth class
```

Any solution to this?

Comment: Can you tell us in which step you got this error?

Comment: How is this related to Composer or Github? Is there any code involved that you could share?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$this->load->library('hybridauth');
```

in your controller to load the library.

Answer (score 0):

application/composer.json

```
{
   "require" : {
     "hybridauth/hybridauth" : "~3.0"
   },
   "config": {
     "platform": {
       "php": "X.X.XX" //SET your php version
     }
  }
}
```

and change config file `application/config/config.php`

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;
```